# How to convert 2015 June 1 into date format in python

Tags: python, datetime

How to convert 2015 June 1 into date format  in python like  `date_object = datetime.date(2014, 12, 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the format - `'%Y %B %d'` along with `datetime.datetime.strptime()` method to convert string to date. Where `%Y` is 4 digit year, `%B` is complete month name, and `%d` is date.

Example/Demo -

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2015 June 1','%Y %B %d')
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2015 June 1','%Y %B %d').date()
datetime.date(2015, 6, 1)
```

Use the first one, if you are content with `datetime` object, if you want the `date()` object itself, you can use the second one.

Comment: Thank u ,
how can i pass month as a variable and that convert in to corresponding digits?
ie, 
month = self.request.post('month');

Comment: after parsing the month , you can use `date.month` to get its digit.

Comment: @VineethaKD I see that you have unaccepted the answer, did you face any issue? Was the answer wrong?

Comment: No your answer is helpful for me, but have an issue when the month is pass as a variable

Comment: What do you mean as a variable? Can you show how you are passing it?

Comment: @VineethaKD Also, I believe if the answer helped you , you should accept it and if you have a new question, ask a new question by clicking on the `Ask a question` button on top.

Comment: Also, if you want I can continue to help you, just let me know what you meant by variable? how is it passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date constructor

```
 >>> from datetime import date
 >>> date_object = date(year=2015, month=6, day=1)
 >>> print date_object 
 2015-06-01
```